# sails flash validation not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, sails.js

I am trying to validate the values in the controller and send the flash error message to the EJS view file in Sailsjs Framework.

I am getting the following error message:

```
 if(flash && flash.err) { 
>>   flash is not defined in ejs file.
```

I have added the flash policy in config/policies.js

```
 '*': 'flash',
```

And this is how I am redirecting to the error view..

```
var usernamePasswordRequiredError = [{
                      name: 'usernamePasswordRequired',
                      message: 'You must enter both a username and password.'
                    }]

                    req.session.flash = {
                      err: usernamePasswordRequiredError
                    }

                   res.redirect("/user/loginpage");
                   return;
```

**Flash.js content**

```
 Policy File:
    module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.flash = {};
    if(!req.session.flash) return next();
    res.locals.flash = _.clone(req.session.flash);
    req.session.flash = {};
    next();
};
```

Help me to resolve this **Flash is not defined error** in view files.

Comment: Here's a screencast on implementing a flash message in sails http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/27/building-a-sails-application-ep4-handling-validation-errors-with-a-flash-message/

Answer (score 3):

Sails.js has `connect-flash` baked-in, so I'm using this:

*On the server, to set:*

```
req.flash('info', 'OHai');
```

*On the client, to get:*

```
res.req.flash('info');
```

This means I don't have to mess around with `_.clone()` or that big gist, and if you do multiple `req.flash('info', '...');` calls, you get an array of all the values when you retrieve it on the client-side. Of course, you can use whatever label (not just 'info') you want too.

Let me know if you need more detail.

Answer (score 1):

With the `flash` policy suggested in [irlnathan's screencast](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/27/building-a-sails-application-ep4-handling-validation-errors-with-a-flash-message/), the `res.locals.flash` object should be defined, at least equal to `{}`, hence Express should not throw the error you got.

But policies apply only to *controllers*, not to mere views.

Did you make sure sails serves the `ejs` view from a controller, not from the main `config/routes.js` configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty close to a gist I saw and I like this approach a bit more than yours. It's kind of the same in spirit but the setting of the flash error and notice messages occur in the policy.

https://gist.github.com/BenBarber/5700061